# Set Progress bar for NSURLConnection with Post method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to set the progress bar for nsurlconection for post method, 
please look up the code and guide to set progress bar, I am trying all possible ways given on this site.

```
    -(void)getCustomerDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)tempDir
{
    self.downloadedMutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[CommonFunctions getPListFileValue:@"wsgetcustomers"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [tempDir setObject:[self md5:[CommonFunctions getPListFileValue:@"udid"]] forKey:@"encryptedvenderid"];
    [tempDir setObject:[CommonFunctions getPListFileValue:@"username"] forKey:@"username"];
    [tempDir setObject:[CommonFunctions getPListFileValue:@"password"] forKey:@"password"];
    [tempDir setObject:[CommonFunctions getPListFileValue:@"version"] forKey:@"version"];

    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tempDir
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];

    // Create the request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"cache-control"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    self.connectionManager = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                  delegate:self];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%lld", response.expectedContentLength);
    self.urlResponse = response;
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.downloadedMutableData appendData:data];

    self.progressBar.progress = ((100.0/self.urlResponse.expectedContentLength)*self.downloadedMutableData.length)/100;

    NSLog(@"%.0f%%", ((100.0/self.urlResponse.expectedContentLength)*self.downloadedMutableData.length));
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.progressBar.hidden = YES;

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data", (unsigned long)[self.downloadedMutableData length]);

    NSDictionary *Response = [[[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.downloadedMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] JSONValue];
    NSDictionary *FinalDict = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Response objectForKey:@"d"]] JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",FinalDict);

}
```

In this code while in the getCustomerDetails, its not calculating the data get in didrecievedata method and directly navigate to didfinish method.

Please help me to add progress bar in my project.

Comment: MD5 is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection  didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
    {
     float prog = (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100);
     [self.progBar setProgress:prog];

    }
```

for progress of data

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I have tried this solution but its not working, i think this method used to send data not to download the data. i want to show the data downloading progress bar.

Comment: NSLog(@"%ld", (long)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)totalBytesWritten);
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)bytesWritten);
    
    float prog = (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100);
    NSLog(@"%f", prog);
    [self.progressBar setProgress:prog]; and my console display the logs totalBytesExpectedToWrite : 143
totalBytesWritten: 143
bytesWritten: 143
prog: 100.000000

Comment: Yes still not working, Directly shows 100% progress on progress bar

Comment: please try with bigger size file